# Input with Watermark (css & Jquery)

Tags: jquery, css

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":input[data-watermark]").each(function () {
        $(this).val($(this).attr("data-watermark"));
        $(this).bind('focus', function () {
            if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("data-watermark")) $(this).val('');
        });
        $(this).bind('blur', function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).val($(this).attr("data-watermark"));
            $(this).css('color','#a8a8a8');
        });
    });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<label>Name: </label>
<input class="input" type="text" name="name" maxlength="" data-watermark="My Name" />
```

#### CSS

```
.input{
    width:190px;
    height:16px;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-left:6px;
    color:#000;
    font-size: 0.688em;
    border:#8c9cad 1px solid;
}
```

What I would like to fix is that whenever the watermarks is in value of the input that the color of the text should be **grey** (`#a8a8a8`). And when the value is something the user writes, then the color should be **black**.

This is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qGvAf/

Comment: `<input type="text" placeholder="This is a watermark" />` is the HTML5 way to do placeholder text.

Comment: And don't write your own `placeholder` polyfill for older browsers, use one of the many already existing ones.

Comment: "watermark" is strange word for placeholders, maybe replace that in the title for search-engine issues;

Comment: Note that `.data('watermark')` is the prefered way to access `.attr("data-watermark")`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":input[data-watermark]").each(function () {
        $(this).val($(this).attr("data-watermark"));
        $(this).css("color","#a8a8a8");
        $(this).bind("focus", function () {
            if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("data-watermark")) $(this).val('');
            $(this).css("color","#000000");
        });
        $(this).bind("blur", function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') 
            {
                $(this).val($(this).attr("data-watermark"));
                $(this).css("color","#a8a8a8");
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).css("color","#000000");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: should post an explanation of what you did when you post a code block

Answer (score 23):

Your desired behaviour of "Input with Watermark" has already been done - it's called the [`placeholder` attribute](http://developers.whatwg.org/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute). It [works in modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/forms).

For older browsers, you should use a [jQuery plugin](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder) to emulate `placeholder` for you.

Lastly, to set the colour, you need CSS similar to this:

```css
.placeholder {
    color: #a8a8a8;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #a8a8a8;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #a8a8a8;
}
```

Unfortunately, you can't combine the above rules; [it won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728360/why-can-i-not-group-browser-specific-css-selectors-for-different-browsers).

Answer (score 1):

Don't override existing value's

I'll had a small problem with this nice solution, but with a little change solved, like to share it.

Just add the `if` statement on line 3 to prevent override loaded value's.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.watermark').each(function () {
    // add the line below
        if (this.value == '') {
            $(this).val($(this).attr("data-watermark"));
            $(this).css("color", "#a8a8a8");
            $(this).bind("focus", function () {
                if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("data-watermark"))         
                $(this).val('');
                $(this).css("color", "#000000");
            });
            $(this).bind("blur", function () {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    $(this).val($(this).attr("data-watermark"));
                    $(this).css("color", "#a8a8a8");
                }
                else {
                    $(this).css("color", "#000000");
                }
            });
    // Don't forget the closing bracket
        }
    })
});
```

Hope it's useful.