# Clear the text in textfield JavaScript

Tags: javascript, textfield

I want to clear the text in textfield, for example if you go to the
[gmail account signup](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?continue=https://accounts.google.com/ManageAccount)
You can see that text will cleared after you start typing,
so simple

`document.getElementById("FirstName").value = "";` won't work, word `First` still going to be over there.

So how to clear it?
Thank you.

Comment: It does work provided the element exists at the time of the call and has the id `FirstName`

Comment: I think this has what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108207/how-do-i-make-an-html-text-box-show-a-hint-when-empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a closer look at the HTML.  The string `First` isn't a value of the text box but a SPAN that is placed over it via CSS.

```
<label id="firstname-label" class="firstname">
  <strong>First name</strong>
  <input id="FirstName" type="text" spellcheck="false" name="FirstName" value="" n="1">
  <span id="firstname-placeholder" class="placeholder-text" style="display: block;">First</span>
</label>
```

The technique is sometimes called a [watermark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433589/input-with-watermark-css-jquery).

**As for how to change the value and hide the SPAN**

As soon as the input has a value (it looks like it is bound on the keyUp event) this inline style is added to the span `display: none;`.  If you wanted to programmatically set `input#FirstName` and clear the span you would need to either programmatically fire the event that is triggering the hiding or also programmatically hide the span (it looks like each input that has a placeholder value uses the ID `<input ID>-placeholder` so you could guess the correct span based on the ID of the input you are setting)

Comment: good point, but let me change the question now, how to clear span?

Comment: thank you very very much!!! I did `document.getElementById("firstname-placeholder").style.display = "none";` and it's gone )))